# Why am i getting this OpenCV error Assertion Failed?

Tags: opencv

Here is the code :

```
Mat _orange = imread("orange.jpg");
Mat_<Vec3f> orange;
_orange.convertTo(orange, orange.type(), 1.0/255.0);
```

The `_orange.convertTo(orange, orange.type(), 1.0/255.0);` part causes the error.

Here is the error message:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in unknown function.

PS:
I am using Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.4

Comment: What does `_orange.channels()` return?

Comment: it returns 3 for _orange.channels().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add parameter to your imread like this :

```
cv::imread("orange.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR );
```

Comment: I did the same thing as you and I can do it in my project. The difference it I'm using 2.4.5 and VS2010. But this not suppose to be a problem. So maybe have a look to your include and lib.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `cv::Mat::convertTo()` method is calling the `cv::Mat::create()` method to allocate memory for the data in your variable `orange`. You should try to replace `orange.type()` by `CV_32F` to make it work.

Comment: This was my initial approach unfortunately it gives the same error.